# find adjoint operator of an operator A

Tags: functional-analysis

How to find adjoint operator of an operator A
$$A \in B(C^1[0,1], C[0,1])$$ $$ (Ax)(t) = x'(t)?$$
In answer : for any functional $f_y$ originated by function $y \in BV_0[0,1]:A(f'_y) = g_z$, where functional $g_z$ originated by couple of function $z(t) = y(t)$ and number zero.

Have no idea how to find. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Is $A$ even bounded? What norm are we using?

Comment: @SmileyCraft for C[0,1] :$\parallel x \parallel = max | x(t)|$, where $t \in [0,1]$

Comment: And for $x\in C^1[0,1]$?

Comment: @SmileyCraft $\parallel x\parallel =max|x'(t)|$, where $t\in[0,1]$

Comment: Then $A$ is not bounded. Consider $f_n(t)=t^n$. Then $\|f_n\|=1$, but $\|Af_n\|=n$, since $f_n'(t)=nt^{n-1}$.

Comment: @SmileyCraft sorry, I  had made a mistake. for x $\in C^1[0,1]$ $\parallel x \parallel = max \parallel x ^{(k)}\parallel_{C[0,1]}$ where $0\leqslant k \leqslant 1$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88027/discussion-between-gera-slanova-and-smileycraft).

Answer (score 3):

Take $\mu\in C[0,1]^*$. By definition, $A^*\mu\in C^1[0,1]^*$ is given by 
$$
(A^*\mu)(f)=\mu(Af)=\mu(f')=\int_{[0,1]}\,f'\,d\mu. 
$$